# WARN in Log file

Tags: artifactory

When are we looking at the logs (/var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/log/console.log
), we can see next picture in many place:

2021-10-07T11:58:37.772Z 35[jfob ] [INFO ] [06640885d968439e] [shipping_service.go:79        ] [main                ] - Validating if shipping need to be enabled or not... [shipping_service]

2021-10-07T11:58:37.775Z 35[jfob ] [WARN ] [06640885d968439e] [shipping_service.go:86        ] [main                ] - Shipping is not enabled in Platform Configuration [shipping_service]

We viewed https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Logging and didn't see any Level with "jfob" name.
We viewed /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/etc/system.full-template.yaml and didn't see any config key with "shipping" name.
Please tell me how to get rid of these notifications in the log file?

Comment: Can you share the system.yaml here? Is the Artifactory version 7.27?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@vsgonchar Hi, The messages you have shared here are related to [Insight service](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+Release+Notes#ArtifactoryReleaseNotes-Artifactory7.27.3). Please be informed that these warnings/informational messages would not have an impact on the Artifactory's performance and it can be safely ignored. In future versions, these messages are discussed to be amended as a part of DEBUG mode enablement.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Have a nice day!